# How can I upgrade libxml2 package on CentOS 6?

Tags: centos, rpm

On CentOS 6.5, when I am trying to upgrade the libxml2 package with:

`yum localinstall libxml2-2.9.1-99.1.src.rpm`

I am receiving the following output:

```
Examining libxml2-2.9.1-99.1.src.rpm: libxml2-2.9.1-99.1.src
Cannot add package libxml2-2.9.1-99.1.src.rpm to transaction. Not a compatible   architecture: src
Nothing to do
```

My current libxml2 version is libxml2-2.7.6-14.el6_5.2.x86_64.

Using `rpm -Uvh libxml2-2.9.1-2.1.rpm`, this output is proceeded:

```
warning: libxml2-2.9.1-2.1.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 3aa2aa5b: NOKEY
1:libxml2                ########################################### [100%]
```

Actually, nothing is changed, when I am listing the installed packages, the old libxml packages is still active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have incompatible versions between the **libxml** package and his dependencies, try to use the next version of **libxml** by upgrading all libraries and packages on your machine.

Answer (score 2):

```
localinstall libxml2-2.9.1-99.1.src.rpm
```

This is a source code rpm, it contains sources, not binary, you should use rpmbuild before trying to install it.

About that, i'm confused, you give 2 differents rpm names ?

```
yum localinstall libxml2-2.9.1-99.1.src.rpm
```

and

```
rpm -Uvh libxml2-2.9.1-2.1.rpm
```

Is it because you already used rpmbuild ?
If it's the case, you should have no problem.

Plus, be aware that you are trying to install a 32 bits version of your library, and you are on a 64 bits OS (as you say your version of libxml2 is libxml2-2.7.6-14.el6_5.2.x86_64)

Comment: after building the binary from `libxml2-2.9.1-99.1.src.rpm`, when I am trying to install the .rpm with `rpm -Uvh libxml2-2-2.9.1-99.1.x86_64.rpm` the following error has been thrown: `file /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2 from install of libxml2-2-2.9.1-99.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libxml2-2.7.6-14.el6_5.2.x86_64`.